# XMLHttpRequest responseText compared to .innerHTML or .firstChild.nodeValue

Tags: javascript

Both of the options shown here seem to work. I'm not certain which is best to use; however, I am actually trying to get a slightly different code to work which is shown below the the working code. I can't figure that out.

```js
var fruit="apple";
var fruit_u=0;
var car="Honda";
var car_u=0;

function update_fruit()
{
  if(document.getElementById("fruit_name").firstChild.nodeValue != fruit)
  {
    document.getElementById("fruit_name").firstChild.nodeValue = fruit;
    fruit_u++;
    document.getElementById("fruit_updates").firstChild.nodeValue = fruit_u;
  }
}

const myInterval_fruit = setInterval(update_fruit,1000);


function update_car()
{
  if(document.getElementById("car_name").innerHTML != car)
  {
    document.getElementById("car_name").innerHTML = car;
    car_u++;
    document.getElementById("car_updates").firstChild.nodeValue = car_u;
  }
}

const myInterval_car = setInterval(update_car,1000);
```

```html
<div id="fruit_name">orange</div><div id="fruit_updates">None</div><br>
<div id="car_name">Toyota</div><div id="car_updates">None</div><br>
```

The above works but if I use the same concept with this code it does not...

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       if(document.getElementById("fruit_name").firstChild.nodeValue != xhttp.responseText)
       {
            document.getElementById("fruit_name").firstChild.nodeValue = xhttp.responseText;
       }
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "~~URL I GET DATA FROM~~", true);
xhttp.send();
```

The data provided at the URL stays constant for the purpose of testing this code... same date provided each time

**UPDATE:** I figured out that comparing `document.getElementById("fruit_name").firstChild.nodeValue` to `xhttp.responseText` will never be equal but if create another temp element like "fruit_name_temp" and I set the temp value like this
`document.getElementById("fruit_name_temp").firstChild.nodeValue = xhttp.responseText;` and then compare the 2 elements "fruit_name" and "fruit_name_temp", they are equal. I am clueless why I can't just compare to `xhttp.responseText` directly.

Comment: I bet the request to `~~URL I GET DATA FROM~~` failed it could be status 0 or 400. If you request to resource change `this.status == 200` to `[200, 201].includes(this.status)`

Comment: @TachibanaShin - See the update above